# How to remove space between words inside paragraph in HTML

Tags: html

I wrote a paragraph in HTML but in browser(mobile view) there is extra space between words here is output at mobile view:-
[Here is Sample][1]k.imgur.com/jfDLE.jpg

and here is the paragraph inside code

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>para</title>
<head>
<body>
<p>Dr.Babasaheb Ambedkar being the inspiration,the MSWS works for the upliftment of deprived and depressed society educationally,morally and ethically to ignite theirs minds so an to lead a dignified life.
</p>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make sure to provide proper images

Comment: If you have a css file then use a ```p {
  word-spacing: 30px;
}``` inside your css  or use this within your html ```<p style="word-spacing: 10px;">Dr.Babasaheb Ambedkar being the inspiration,the MSWS works for the upliftment of deprived and depressed society educationally,morally and ethically to ignite theirs minds so an to lead a dignified life.
</p>``` use the appropriate value you need inside of word-spacing

Comment: and i tried viewing this in mobile and it does not give such a mistake for me, but still try adding this below html tag ```<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Comment: i try but it  create more space between words and my screen shot is not clear. The problem is it has more space when load in browser specially in mobile view.

Comment: it does no such thing for me anyway try adding those meta to you html and it might go

Comment: Can you please check this simple site at mswsa.org you may find it. try to view in mobile view. I try lot nothing happen.

Comment: yes i visited the site, and the reason for their wrod spacing is that they have such style applied in their css ```@media (max-width: 991px)
.para {
    font-size: 15px;
    word-spacing: 7px;
}``` this is for the mobile view part and they have word spacing, even for desktop they have wordspacing applied ```.para {
    margin-top: 40px;
    word-spacing: 7px;```

Comment: ok did you try to revome that css if you don't mind. I thought that if i give word space then it will remove space but nothing change that why i gave word space.

Comment: wordspacing is to give wrodspacing, in the website you jus gave, i tried removing wrodspacing and the words were placed together. Wich browser r u using to view

Comment: chrome and monzilla

Comment: in your code there is no error, idk why your viewing is showing errors :(

Comment: i also don't know where is the mistake.

Comment: ill just giv u ans and mayb that vl work or mayb that wont, still i dont know whats causing it :(

Comment: thanks it solve half of the problem. I try your answer code separately its work but still same problem when i try to put with main file.

Comment: what is the main file? mayb tht is wer the issue is

Comment: index.html  file

Comment: can u paste tht too? mayb some styles are colliding and thats wer the issue is

Comment: ok you want to see my  index file.

Comment: yes please there might be some mistakes there?

Comment: can you please check from github. here

Comment: https://github.com/chakmakamal/error

Comment: ok i figured out the problem, ur div with class abt-mswsa-article1 has text-align: justify ;and that is causing this issue here, remove it and youll b good to go

Comment: problem sloved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your CSS file in div with class `abt-mswsa-article1`. Just remove the `text-align` inside of it.

```css
.abt-mswsa-article1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #035aa6;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: 16.5%;
}
```